Building a dropdown menu component in Angular 17
I'm trying to create a dropdown menu placed in a component in angular 17. I have a navbar where just the logo is placed, and then on the right I have the component:

This is the HTML:
<div class="lang-btn">
  <button class="change-lang" (click)="isClicked()">
    <img
      src="../../../assets/navbar/it-button.png"
      alt="it-IT"
      class="lang-img"
    />
  </button>
</div>
<div class="langs-btn" *ngIf="isOpen">
  <ul class="lang-ul">
    <li class="lang-li">
      <button class="change-langs">
        <img
          src="../../../assets/navbar/en-button.png"
          alt="en-UK"
          class="lang-img"
        />
        <h6 class="lang">ENGLISH</h6>
      </button>
    </li>
    <li class="lang-li">
      <button class="change-langs">
        <img
          src="../../../assets/navbar/es-button.png"
          alt="es-ES"
          class="lang-img"
        />
        <h6 class="lang">ESPAÑOL</h6>
      </button>
    </li>
    <li class="lang-li">
      <button class="change-langs">
        <img
          src="../../../assets/navbar/fr-button.png"
          alt="fr-FR"
          class="lang-img"
        />
        <h6 class="lang">FRANÇAIS</h6>
      </button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

and this is the component:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dropdown-lang',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  templateUrl: './dropdown-lang.component.html',
  styleUrl: './dropdown-lang.component.css'
})
export class DropdownLangComponent {
  isOpen = false;
  isClicked() {
    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen
  }
}

why is not working as intended?
PS: If you note on :hover they are not exactly aligned. The px are right but I don't know how it is not as precise as it should be
I tried at first using bootstrap but it didn't work. I tried to put everything in the navbar in the app.component but it also didn't work.

Enclosed all in a div. NOTE: Use box-sizing: border-box; to make your buttons have the same width with or without border. NOTE, really a "dropdown menu" in a nav-bar is some that resolve multiple libraries, bootstrap, ng-bootstrap, material-angular, ....

Here's an example component that uses the angular CDK. Here's how to use it
